# How can I test the Remember Me checkbox

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am currently setting up a service allowing user login on a web portal, for comfort I have added the "Remember Me" function using Spring Security by using a persistent approach that stores tokens in DB for a defined time.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeCookieName("ugeddit-cookie")
        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
        .tokenValiditySeconds(172800);

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

How is it possible to write a test covering this case, without adding too many dependencies to the project?

I can see at the moment how to add a User and simulate a connection to the formLogin but I can't see what method can allow me to simulate the activation of the "Remember Me" checkbox

```java
@Test
void whenRememberedUser_TokenIsAddedInDB() throws Exception {
    User user = new User(1L, "test", "$2a$10$/fAVkMGa6gHeM6Q0VHJyFOTznAo3qrXbj5CF0ZvMhxVldxYbxnk/6", "ROLE_USER");
    userRepo.save(user);
 
    mvc.perform(formLogin("/login").user("test").password("spring")).andExpect(authenticated());
}
```